# Displaying different colored string in one QTableWidget cell

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a QTableWidget with a specific cell structure. In one cell I want to display a String, or more specific two strings in different colors. example:

cell beginning {string in red , string in green, string in blue} cell end

Is there a easier way of archiving this, than subclassing a QItemDeelegate item?
If not, my idea was to subclass a delegate, creating inside the delegate a QTextBrowser, which can handle HTML. Then I can pass the String with the associated color to the Item and display them?

What do you think, is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [QTableWidget::setCellWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget) method to set [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) as a cell widget wich supports `html` formatting.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, under normal circumstances this would be the solution. Sadly I have to fill the QTableWidget in a QThread, and it is not possible to set a Widget to a cell inside a thred wich is not part of the gui :(